# Duda respecto al uso de variables en PHP-HTML-JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html5, backend

Tengo un formulario básico en HTML donde tengo este boton que se repite N veces según cada respuesta obtenida de una query

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="<?=$datos->id_reserva?>" id="mostrar">Ver detalle</button>
```

Donde id_reserva lo obtengo de una Query a la base de datos. Y de aquí nace mi duda ¿Puedo por medio de AJAX cargar, en un div asignado para ello, el detalle de cada reserva enviando el valor correspondiente por el value del boton?.

Pienso en hacer algo como esto:

El div

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="detalle">
        
</div>
```

El AJAX

```
$("#mostrar").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bd/detalle.php",
            data: "mostrar=" + $("#mostrar").val(),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#detalle").html(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Y en el PHP sería algo como esto

```
<?php 

$dato  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mostrar', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$id = $dato;

$q_busqueda = "SELECT....."
?>

<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h4>Detalle.....
</div>
```

Espero se entienda mi duda, saludos!

Comment: La mejor forma de resolver la duda es probando, pero ya te adelanto un potencial problema: el id de cada botón debe ser único, no puedes usar "mostrar" en todos o no podrás seleccionar fácilmente el que quieres

Comment: Lo solucioné usando "document.querySelector('input[name="documento"]:checked').value;"

Answer (score 0):

Pego una posible solución que trabajé durante el día, por si a alguien le pueda ser de utilidad

Formulario HTML (con datos de ejemplo, se puede llenar con datos de una query)

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <h4>Tus prácticas inscritas</h4>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Asignatura</td>
                <td>Lugar de práctica</td>
                <td>Fecha de inicio</td>
                <td>Fecha de termino</td>
                <td>Documentos de práctica</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Practica 1</td>
                <td>Practica 1</td>
                <td>Practica 1</td>
                <td>Practica 1</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="documento" value="Documento 1">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Practica 2</td>
                <td>Practica 2</td>
                <td>Practica 2</td>
                <td>Practica 2</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="documento" value="Documento 2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Practica 3</td>
                <td>Practica 3</td>
                <td>Practica 3</td>
                <td>Practica 3</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="documento" value="Documento 3">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="enviar">Ver documentos</button>
    </form>
    <br>
</div>
```

El AJAX (se asigna el valor de un radio en estado "checked" a una variable, que después se envía)

```
$("#enviar").click(function(){
        valorActivo = document.querySelector('input[name="documento"]:checked').value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bd/documentos_practica.php",
            data: "enviar=" + valorActivo,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#documentos_practica").html(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Y el documento PHP sería el mismo.